# How to handle material ui's select with 2 same values

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement a feature in which user can enter his phone number along with his country code.
I am using material-ui's Select component for country code's dropdown so that user can select his country code from dropdown menu.
problem is `usa` & `canada` have same country code i.e `+1`. i am also using a npm package show correspnding country flag.
here's my code:-

```
            const checkCountryFlag = (code) => {
              switch (code) {
                 case "+91":
                    return "inr";
                 case "+1":
                    return "usd";
                 case "+44":
                    return "gbp";
                 case "+971":
                     return "aed";
                  case "+1-c":
                     return "cad";
                 }
               };

                <Select
                    value={countryCode}
                    label="Country code"
                    onChange={(e) => setCountryCode(e.target.value)}
                    renderValue={() => (
                      <div style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
                        <div
                          class={`currency-flag currency-flag-${checkCountryFlag(
                            countryCode
                          )}`}
                          style={{ paddingRight: "5px" }}
                        ></div>
                        <span style={{ paddingLeft: "20px" }}>{countryCode}</span>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value={`+91`}>
                      <div class={`currency-flag currency-flag-inr`}></div>
                      +91
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={`+1`}>
                      <div class={`currency-flag currency-flag-usd`}></div>
                      +1
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={`+44`}>
                      <div class={`currency-flag currency-flag-gbp`}></div>
                      +44
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={`+971`}>
                      <div class={`currency-flag currency-flag-aed`}></div>
                      +971
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={`+1`}>
                      <div class={`currency-flag currency-flag-cad`}></div>
                      +1
                    </MenuItem>
                  </Select>
```

as you can see above...canada & usa have same country code so either I select usa or canada, my switch case will always return `usa`.

I tried to give a different value to `value` prop in MenuItem which represents canada i.e `'+1-c'` then on selecting my Select shows `+1-c` which is so obvious.

I also tried to do check in value prop of select component like this :-

```
              <Select
                value={countryCode !== "+1-c" ? countryCode : "+1"}
                label="Country code"
                onChange={(e) => setCountryCode(e.target.value)}
                renderValue={() => (
                  <div style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
                    <div
                      class={`currency-flag currency-flag-${checkCountryFlag(
                        countryCode
                      )}`}
                      style={{ paddingRight: "5px" }}
                    ></div>
                    <span style={{ paddingLeft: "20px" }}>
                      {countryCode !== "+1-c" ? countryCode : "+1"}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                )}
              >
                 <MenuItem.....
              </Select>
```

In this case...when i select canada...then i am unable select usa again

Any suggestions that how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is, do not set country code as value, set only country name.

And upon selection, extract the country code from the selected country.

For example.

If the user selects Canada. You just set Canada in the state, and get the country code for Canada from the find function.

```
[{name: "Canada", code: "+1"}, {name: "USA", code: "+1"}].find(c => c.name === selectedCountryName).code
```